# Formatting text for chord and song lyrics Textview or UiLabel Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitextview

could anyone give me some tips on how to implement in a textview or label, formatting text for chord and song lyrics? Kind of image below?

[image]

Comment: what is G Bm Em Em7 ?

Comment: musical notes (Chords)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have the same challenge as mine. I'm thinking about drawing text on a CATextLayer object every time i found [G] or [Em] in my lyric text like: "[G]I read the [Bm]news today, oh [Em]boy, [Em7]"

```
func drawLayer(_ chord: String, frame: CGRect) {
    let textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.frame = frame

    let myAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 13.0) , // font
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.cyan                    // text color
    ]
    let myAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: chord, attributes: myAttributes )

    textLayer.string = myAttributedString
    lyricView.layer.addSublayer(textLayer)
}
```

The difficult part is to determine the position of every single chord, you must specify it's position exactly at the top of your lyric. (i'm still searching the best method to get the x & y position)

Comment: have you found any solution for this?